# Should I use <aside> for off-canvas navigation?

Tags: navigation, accessibility, css

I want to create an accessible off-canvas navigation and most tutorials say you should put it inside the `<aside>` element, however, since it is my main navigation which will appear on one line on desktop, wouldn't it be un-semantical to put it inside `<aside>` ?

Here is my current code:

```
<nav id="primary-nav" aria-label="Main Navigation">
<ul class="container">
 <li>
    <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Meet Stefany</a>
  </li>
   etc...
  </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it correctly.  [Navigation areas](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/page-structure/regions/#navigation) should be in a <nav> element (or a <div> with role="navigation").  You even have an `aria-label` for your <nav> - bravo!

> most tutorials say you should put it inside the  element

Do you have a reference for such a tutorial?

The [html spec for <aside>](https://www.w3.org/TR/html53/sections.html#the-aside-element) does say it could be used for **groups** of <nav> elements, so I suppose that's one reference, but I'm not sure I've seen *groups* of <nav> elements before.

> The element can be used for typographical effects like pull quotes or sidebars, for advertising, for groups of <nav> elements, and for other content that is considered separate from the main content of the nearest ancestor sectioning content.

So the navigation elements themselves (often a list) should be contained in a <nav> but the <nav> itself *might* be contained in an <aside>.  I've never organized my navigation elements that way.

Comment: Here is one tutorial https://www.taniarascia.com/off-canvas-navigation/ and https://github.com/vmitsaras/js-offcanvas those folks use ```<aside>``` and they claim to be accessible, hence my confusion. THANK YOU so much for helping! 

P.S. Heh, I wasn't sure if the aria-label was redundant, thanks!

Comment: the first example doesn't say anything about being accessible.  the second example, if you follow it to https://codepen.io/vmitsaras/pen/gwGwJE, does work pretty well with regards to keyboard accessibility.  the navigation area should be in a <nav> rather than "complementary" (<aside>) but that's a minor issue.  the fact that they put their navigation into an <aside> doesn't make it accessible.  it's all the other stuff they did.

Comment: and regarding the `aria-label` on your <nav> example, if you only have one <nav>, then you don't necessarily need a label.  if you have more than one, definitely put unique labels on each one.  but even with one, it's nice to have a label.  but you should not have the word "navigation" in the label because you're already using the <nav> element which will be announced as "navigation" by the screen reader.  just like you don't need "button" in a button label.